# How to get memory usage of each Python program in sh script file?

Tags: python, linux, bash, debian

I have 2 separate Python programs (for example myp1.py and myo2.py) must be running in Debian. It appears system memory consumes a lot. So I try to detect memory usage of each .py and decide to relaunch .py in a sh script that triggered by crontab.
Is it possible to have any hint for the commands used to grab memory usage of each .py in sh script please?

Comment: BTW, if any hint for resolving memory  consumption issue will be appreciated too.

Comment: can you test this in a bash file `ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax | grep python | while read pid user mem command; do
    echo "PID: $pid, User: $user, Memory Usage: $mem%, Command: $command"
done`?

Comment: PythnMemUsg=$(ps -C python -o vsz |sed 's/^.*VSZ//g')
echo "PythnMemUsg=" $PythnMemUsg

Above is what I’ve tried, but dunno how to extract each memory usage from PythnMemUsg.

Comment: Thanks Ali, I’ll try the pid way. But can you give comments for the way I did which is shown above?

Comment: the downside is that it will take all the pids that use Python, not just the scripts you ar looking for their memory usage. but I believe you could create a filter by the names of the filter in bash and it is all set.

Comment: Yes. I’m trying to learn how to create the filter. Long way for me.

Answer (score 0):

In `/proc/[pid]/status` there is a lot of information about the process.  You would be interested in the fields VmPeak and VmSize.

You state that you have a lot of memory consumption. I don't know where you got that value from, but you should look at the output of `vmstat 5 5` if there is a memory problem on your system.

Memory on Linux is used as much as possible. In the `vmstst`, you will see that quite a lot is used for cache. That makes the system faster. Do not look at the `free` column; it says little about the actual use of memory for processes.

Memory becomes a problem when the columns `si` and `so` are high. On most modern systems, they are 0 or occasionally 1 or 2. These columns indicate how much memory is swapped in and out to disk.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I’ll try to study harder.

Answer (score 0):

here is the bash code to run (make sure the .sh file is executable - use chmod-):

```
ps -o pid,%mem,command ax | grep python | while read pid mem command; do echo "PID: $pid, Memory Usage: $mem%, Command: $command" 
done
```

save the file (FILENAME.sh), then execute `sudo chmod 777 FILENAME.sh`, then you can execute the following to see all PIDs that use python and see how much memory they are using:

```
./FILENAME.sh
```

In order to filter based on specific Python script names, you could use grep with the bash script to filter them out:

```
./FILENAME.sh | grep -E '(REGEX_PATTERN)'
```

make sure to use the flag -E to use the regex engine and then pass the regex_pattern (the filename pattern) you are looking for.

***An example I used to test it:***

```
./test.sh | grep -E '(server.py|lsp_server.py)'
```

I got the following:

```
 PID: 333540, Memory Usage: 0.1%, Command:
 /home/XXXX/.pyenv/versions/XXXX/XXX/python
 /home/XXXX/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.isort-2022.8.0/bundled/tool/***server.py***

 PID: 333543, Memory Usage: 0.2%, Command:
 /home/XXXX/.pyenv/versions/XXXX/XXX/python
 /home/XXXX/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.autopep8-2023.4.0/bundled/tool/***lsp_server.py***
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: do not post text as images. Furthermore, your image does not show what you try to explain.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't show all the text since the path has some personal info, but modified it according to your feedback. Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

I’ve tried following line, it works as expected.

myclientMemUsg=$(ps -eo pid,vsz,cmd |grep 'python.myclient.py' |sed '2d' |awk '{print $2}')

Thanks to all.